# How to fix chipped cement

Tags: concrete, cement, self-leveling-concrete

I chipped the cement on my wall by accident.

[image]

What product can I use to easily fix that?

Do you think I can use [Quikrete](https://www.quikrete.com/pdfs/data_sheet-cgfs%20concrete%20mix%201004-51.pdf)? It's going to be about 0F (or -17C) tonight. What do you think? Will the colors match too?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small-ish tub of ready mix stucco patch should do the trick.

A few notes:

- be sure to knock off anything loose underneath
- check the label for application/curing temperature. It may be too cold to use right now. (I don't know of any product that's specifically designed for cold weather application, though it might exist.)
- a coarse sponge might help you get close to the texture, or you may find that you need to add something to the top layer (like coarse sand). It's not absolutely clear what your existing finish is made up of.

(edit to respond to your edit) I wouldn't use the quikrete you linked. Color is going to be hard to match. If consistency is something you're looking for, you'll probably need to do the entire walls up to the next corner.

Comment: Thanks Aloysius. What if I leave this until spring? Is that a good or bad idea in terms of the situation getting worse because of the cold and moist conditions?

Comment: From the looks of it, only the top coat has been busted off, so I'd think it's fine to leave until spring. One last thought, regarding making it look seamless... stucco paint on a few walls.